# Adding Index Number Row in Result set of Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am adding a index number row in result set of query but its not working here is the query

```
SELECT RevisionId, FileSubmitId,UpdateTimeA, number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UpdateTimeA)
FROM Revisions
WHERE FileSubmitId='20140512212019387'
ORDER BY UpdateTimeA DESC;
```

and here is the error
[image]

I am using MS Access 2010

The query Works fine when i remove this part

```
 number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UpdateTimeA)
```

Comment: Remove ';' at the end of query

Comment: @MeysamTolouee: Same result...

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE As (
SELECT RevisionId, FileSubmitId,UpdateTimeA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UpdateTimeA) number
FROM Revisions
WHERE FileSubmitId='20140512212019387'
)
Select * From CTE ORDER BY UpdateTimeA DESC
```

Comment: yes, it says invalid sql statement, it should start with insert, select, update or delete...

Comment: @AdilWaqar Try adding ';' before 'With'. Like ';With'

Comment: its same.. I just found that MS ACCESS does not support row_number()  .. :(